# "Complete action using" when trying to load in a WebView

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I'm testing the built-in WebView in the Android apps. My problem is that the following code

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

triggers an intent (sugesting the installed browsers for opening the web) instead of open it in the built-in WebView. What should I do for avoiding that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
WebView mWebView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

This won't open other broweser. Have reference here from [DEVELOPER's SITE](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html).

Comment: in shouldOverrideUrlLoading you can just return false and not do view.loadUrl(url)

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) if you want to open URL within your application.

Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) and find **Handling Page Navigation** for the WebViewClient example.