# ShakeActivity 1st launch to be neglected

Tags: java, android

I wanted to create a webview that comes on shakeactivity. In xml of current activity, I made webview visibility as invisibe. Now, I have this shakeevent listener. Everything is working fine, except I start this shakeactivity on its first launch it displays *shaking* in toast in text i included that, which i have in onShake() function. But, I dont want that. I want to neglect the first launch of this shakeactivity and after 2nd shake i want to refresh the shakeactivity to load a url and visibility of webview to visible.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        ShakeEventManager.shakeListener {
    private ShakeEventManager sd;
    private static long back_pressed;
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createData();
        sd = new ShakeEventManager();
        sd.setListener(this);
        sd.init(this);
    }

    private void createData() {
        WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }

    @Override
    public void onShake() {
        count++;
        if (count >= 1) {
            ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(
                    getApplicationContext());
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibrator.vibrate(1000);
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                createData();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Enable Data Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sd.register();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sd.deregister();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide more readable code?

Comment: He dont know how to format so i have edited :) @RandykaYudhistira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `count++` variable increasing value first before checking condition first time so that you may have to increase in `if` as i have done or you can put this statement at the last after condition.

Change like following:

```
    @Override
    public void onShake() {

        if (count++ >= 1) {
            ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(
                    getApplicationContext());
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibrator.vibrate(1000);
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                createData();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Enable Data Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

> Note: I dont have tested but i just saw your code and found this
>   logical mistake so may be helpful to you :)

Comment: Thanks pratik for helpin me out And can you please check the code in createData() function. it is asking me to complete my action using browsers but i want google.com to open in my webview in my activity.

Comment: This will help you... Keep Searching Dear....http://stackoverflow.com/a/10226126/1318946